# Checking if data violates SQL decimal constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, decimal

I have a table that is getting a column changed from a `VARCHAR` to `DECIMAL(20,7)` data type. I need find out what rows have a value in the column that **violates** the `DECIMAL(20,7)` data type and I believe I am close.

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE 
     (ISNUMERIC(columnName)  = 0 and columnName IS NOT NULL)
     OR (columnName LIKE '%,%')
     OR (LEN(columnName) > 20)
```

I think I am mostly hung up on the the `LEN` check, as I can still miss results. Is there a way to get deeper into the length so I can check with precision, instead of just a length of 20?

Comment: SQL server 2005/2008/2012

Comment: sure, check instr for position . and count positions to the right of it.  If >7 you have a problem.  If multiple . you have a problem.  but it seems like a regular expression may do all of this, i'm just terrible at writting them.

Comment: If you have access to a copy of the database, you could add a new column of type `DECIMAL(20, 7)`, then loop through and copy the values from the `varchar` one at at time, noting whichever ones fail.  It's crude, but avoids chasing down every possible condition.

Comment: maybe use a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

You mention SQL Server 2012 in your comment, and for 2012 or later, see if [TRY_PARSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) will work for you.

```
declare @table table (Input varchar(50))

insert @table (Input) 
values ('20,000.0001'), ('abc'), ('1234'), ('0.12345678'), ('1234567891234.1234567')

select Input from @table
where 
    TRY_PARSE(Input as decimal(20,7)) <> TRY_PARSE(Input as decimal(21,8)) 
    or TRY_PARSE(Input as decimal(20,7)) is null

/*
   abc
   0.12345678
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to remove `Isnumeric` function which is going to fail in many cases. Instead add `Like` operator and one more condition. Still there might be some gaps to be filled.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  ( columnName LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'
         AND columnName IS NOT NULL )
        OR ( columnName LIKE '%,%' )
        OR (( columnName LIKE '%.%.%' ))
        OR ( Len(columnName) > 20 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] AS t
WHERE LEN([columnname]) > 21
OR LEN([columnname]) - CHARINDEX('.', [columnname]) > 7
```